# How to calculate the resolution of a video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, resolution, calculation, aspect-ratio

So for 1280x720 it's obvious that resolution equals to 720p with an aspect ratio of 1,777777778 (16:9).

But given the width (560px) and height (320px) of a video, how do I calculate the resolution? Or is it just like using the height of the video? (320px = 320p?) And if not, what's the formula to calculate the resolution?

Because with 560x320 I have an aspect ratio of 1,75 which is close to 16:9 but this doesn't mean it's the same resolution.

Comment: *720p* is a name of a specific format (720p is a synonym for "HD ready" format). The 720p format defines the resolution to be 1280x720 (and defines the 16:9 aspect ratio). 320p is not a format name (as far as I know). **560x320 is the resolution** - there are no shortcuts. Note: The aspect ration is not necessarily 560:320 (7:4), because there are cases when pixels are not perfect squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image resolution is the product of the vertical and horizontal pixels that make up the image.

Therefore the resolution of `1280` x `720` = `921.600` which is higher than `560` x `320` = `179.200`.

Television historically only had a vertical resolution that was discrete. The [horizontal signal was fully analogue](https://superuser.com/a/687919/1137422).

This might be the reason why modern video formats and tv standards use the vertical resolution to refer to the image resolution.

The `p` means progressive. A few years back it was common that frames where not progressive but interlaced (`i`), meaning that one frame contained only the odd lines while the next frame only showed the even lines.

Well, progressive shows a complete frame at a time.